# C - Execv - incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, unix

So what I'm trying to do is to send a simple ping command through Execv and print on terminal.

I have on my original problem an array of strings of unknown arguments. a[n][50] that is going to be filled throughout the execution of the process, accordingly to user input.
I cant manage to use "execv" , I keep receiving "incompatible pointer type".
Trying to illustrate the problem, I did only a simple "ping" "google.com"

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    //That's what I have...
    char a[3][50];
    strcpy(a[0], "ping");
    strcpy(a[1], "google.com");
    
    //First try
    a[2] = NULL;
    execv(a[0], a);    
    
    //Second time, trying to fix, also didnt work 
    char *pointer[3];
    pointer[0] = a[0];
    pointer[1] = a[1];
    pointer[2] = NULL;

    execv(pointer[0], pointer);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any workaround without having to change the a[n][50] format to save strings?

Comment: A 2-dimensional array is not the same as an array of pointers.

Comment: `a[2] = NULL;` is not valid. `a[2]` is an array, you can't assign to an array.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, I'm aware, that's why I've tried to fix on the second try, I've created an array of pointers, pointing to the 2- dimensional array, but it also didnt work =( any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The second version doesn't produce any errors.

Comment: @Barmar, but why it isn't printing anything on my terminal? (FIrst time studying unix processes, still a bit lost)

Comment: Use `execvp()` because you need to find `ping` in `$PATH`

Comment: Or change `a[0]` to be the full path of the `ping` program.

Comment: That's it!!!!!!! exevp()!! Thank you so much!!! =)))

Comment: For future reference, put a `perror("execv failed");` after the `execv` so that you get some feedback when the exec call fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second version will work, but you need to use `execvp()` instead of `execv`, since the first argument isn't the full path of the `ping` program.